# Adding an admin menu page showing the link twice - how to solve this?

Tags: menus, admin

I'm newbie and I'm trying to create a plugin to add a menu to left menu in admin section. 
i have create the page but it is working fine. but i find the left menu being displayed twice. how can I resolve the issue. Find below my code:

```
add_action('admin_menu','user_data');
    function user_data(){
      add_menu_page('User Data','User data','manage_options','user-page','user_data_options');
    }
    function user_data_options(){
        include('user-page.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any submenus under this, sub-menus can duplicate the parent menu item. (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/top-level-menu-duplicated-as-submenu-in-admin-section-plugin and many more).

Or do you mean the left menu is duplicated in full? If so it's probably due to an include in your user-page.php file.